# Calculate the maximum over the interval that satisfies the condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, iteration, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
ID  Zones  Distance
E18 A      0.51
E22 A      3.92
E23 A      1.05
E26 A      0.675
E27 A      2.12
E18 B      0.51
E22 B      3.92
E23 C      1.05
E26 C      0.675
```

What I would like to do is to find the maximum value per interval.
So for example, for the zone "A" the maximum "Distance" is `3.92` and so on for all the "Zones"

I came up with the following loop to subdivide the dataframe into separate "Zones" as a dictionary:

```
  csv_file=new_path+"distance"+".csv"
  distance=pd.read_csv(csv_file, error_bad_lines=False)

  distance_by_zones={}
  zones=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'D']
  for i in range(len(zones)):
   distance_by_zones[i]=distance.loc[distance["Zones"].isin([zones[i]])]
```

This code perfectly subdivides the dataframe into different bunches per each "Zones", for example:

```
  print(distance_by_zones[2])
Unnamed: 0  ID    Zones  Distance
        10  E18     C      0.57
        11  E22     C      4.20
        12  E23     C      1.13
        13  E26     C      0.91
        14  E27     C      2.43
```

What I need to do now, is to calculate the max distance in each of the "Zones". So, for example the output would be: **max_distance_C=4.20**

It would be great if the this operation is performed in the `for loop` above, so I can manipulate the data in a one go...

Comment: `df.groupby('Zones')['Distance'].max()`?

Comment: Something like distance.groupby('zone').max() would do.

Comment: Seeing such a succinct command for a rookie is so satisfying) Thanks! really made my day!